Can you manually add builds to the Visual Studio archive manager?
After running into the long path issue with this package Plugin.Firebase it seems that I can't build using Visual Studio's UI anymore, it only works using CLI commands. This isn't the end of the world, but building via the CLI doesn't populate the archive manager which I do find very useful. So is there a way to manually add builds to the archive manager in Visual Studio?
